# Captions in Chrome browser now at the top of the video player

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using the JWplayer on my site, and with the new Chrome browser update, captions are now appearing at the top of the video player. I have tried some css settings, but have so far been unable to change it's position back to the bottom. Is there a specific css setting that will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried taking out some of the settings I had in place, and after removing 'renderCaptionsNatively: true' the captions worked properly. It now matches how IE and firefox display the captions, so whatever Chrome does natively was causing the issue.